# 2 Submits 1 Works same code?

Tags: php, html

So I have 2 submit buttons no matter what even if i remove all the code from broken button I get a 403 erorr forbidden but the second submit button works...

Here is my html/php code for buttons:

```
<form action="buy.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
<br>
<p></p>
<?php if($row['pp'] == 1){
echo '
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay with Paypal" name="pp">';
} ?>
<p></p>
<?php if($row['btc'] == 1){
echo '
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Pay with Bitcoin" name="btc">';
} ?></form>
```

Code for buttons:

```
if(isset($_POST['btc'])){
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO invoices (itemid, username, email, price, status, type) VALUES (:itemid, :username, :email, :price, :status, :type)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':itemid' => $id, ':username' => $row['username'], ':email' => $email, ':price' => $row['price'], ':status' => "awaiting", ':type' => "btc"));
    $id = $db->lastInsertId();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $row2 = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Only difference is wherever btc is its pp for the broken button.

Comment: From this I dont really get what happens if you submit with the pp button.

Comment: Nothing it just goes to a 403 forbidden access.

Comment: ...and where do you declare your input params (`$id`, the `$row`-array ect) that you use in your db-queries, and in your query string? You need to show us the relevant code, not just snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Pay with Bitcoin" name="btc">` will work because in your php code, you are only posting this `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Pay with Bitcoin" name="btc">`

To achieve your goal,

Use same name for both button but with a different value for each.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay with Paypal" name="btnPay">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Pay with Bitcoin" name="btnPay">
```

Then in your php file:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['btnPay'])){
    if($_POST['btnPay'] == "Pay with Paypal"){
      //code for paypal payment
    }
    else if($_POST['btnPay'] == "Pay with Bitcoin"){
      //code for bitcoin payment
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: ...or simply have a hidden field with btc or pp as value, instead of comparing button labels in the back end (labels change and code will break).

Comment: It depends for the OP on what approach he is intended to use.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.

Comment: Well, his method clearly didn't work, so why not recommend a better approach? :)

Comment: Wait now it doesnt insert into database with this it was inserting before.